# Nativescript - plugin nativescript-ui-pro pie chart refresh

Tags: nativescript

I'm a new dev on this platform and I have a problem with graphics, specifically pie chart, im trying leave dynamic, but the data in the screen continue static, you have any solution for this?

[image]

[image]

devs this is my code

The pie chart

```html
<chart:RadPieChart id="pieChart" height="300" allowAnimation="true" row="1" allowAnimation="true">
    <chart:RadPieChart.series>
      <chart:PieSeries selectionMode="DataPoint" expandRadius="0.4" outerRadiusFactor="0.7" items="{{ pieSource }}" seriesName="pie" valueProperty="Amount" legendLabel="Shift" showLabels="true">
        <chart:PieSeries.labelStyle>
          <chart:PointLabelStyle margin="15"/>
        </chart:PieSeries.labelStyle>
      </chart:PieSeries>
    </chart:RadPieChart.series>

    <chart:RadPieChart.legend>
      <chart:RadLegendView position="Right" title="Turnos - Partic." offsetOrigin="TopRight" width="110" enableSelection="true"/>
    </chart:RadPieChart.legend>
</chart:RadPieChart>
```

and below is the code for updating the graph

```js
loadData(val1: number, val2: number, val3: number) {

        const v1 = val1;
        const v2 = val2;
        const v3 = val3;

        this.set("pieSource",
            [
                { Shift: "T1", Amount: v1 },
                { Shift: "T2", Amount: v2 },
                { Shift: "T3", Amount: v3 }
            ]);

        console.log(this.get("pieSource"));
    }
```

Comment: Rather than including an image of your code, it is easier for potential answerers to respond if you include the code directly in your question.

Comment: First of all, nativescript-ui-pro plugin is deprecated. For charts you must use [nativescript-ui-chart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-ui-chart). What do you mean by "leave dynamic, but the data in the screen continue static"? Is it the chart do not update when you change data?

Comment: Manoj, i use the new plugin, and when I say "leave dynamic, but the data in the screen continue static", my data changes, but the chart don't reload this is my question.

Comment: rlandster, i'll post my code sorry i m new in this session on questions